# Breakers loose in panel a problem?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

So I had an old panel and subpanel replaced with a single new panel. The guys reused the old breakers, and the breakers wobble in the panel like loose teeth. With the old panel, they didn't wobble at all.

Is this because the breakers don't fit the new panel, or were they just not tightened down enough?

The breakers are GE type THQL, 1 pole units. The panel is a GE PowerMark Gold Load Center, type 1 indoor enclosure, model 6.

Comment: What make and model are the breakers involved, the old panel/subpanel, and the new panel?

Comment: Breakers are GE type THQL, 1 pole unit. Panel is GE PowerMark Gold Load Center, type 1 indoor enclosure, model 6. Thanks!

Comment: Related (*almost* a dupe): https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121053/breakers-loose-in-main-panel-does-whole-panel-need-to-be-replaced?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How old were the old panels?  Can we have photos of the listing labels from the *old* main and subpanels?

Comment: I saw that post, but it doesn't answer whether this is something expected, or whether it's the result of the quality of the work that was done.
New line no pictures of the old panel, and I am assuming that they were thrown out when the guys put in this panel, because they're nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2):

### Replace the breakers

I'm not precisely sure what's going on here, but replacement breakers should cure the wobbling issue, once and for all.  It might be an issue with old TQL (or early THQL even?) breakers not fitting properly into a new Q-line panel (as documented [here](https://www.diychatroom.com/f18/old-ge-tql-breakers-short-circuit-current-218842/index2/#post1543809)), or it could simply be that the line-side jaws on your breakers are not in good condition any longer -- either way, the cure is the same.